# Numeric multidimensional array php

Tags: php, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have this numeric multidimensional array in php. It's Playfair matrix and I want to get the keys of a letter from the matrix.

Let's say I have the letter "P", which is on the third row(0 to 4) and second column(0 to 4). I have tried several things array_keys(not working as I want it to), functions to get the key of the first level of the array, making the array one dimensional and doing some magic tricks...Nothing works and I would like some help.

This is the function that gets the keys of the first level:

```
function array_search2($needle, $haystack){
    $l = count($haystack);
    for ($i=0;  $i < $l; $i++) { 
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack[$i])) return $i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to have this array with letters, to get two letters from it, to get these two letters their coordinates(from the PLayfair matrix) and to comprate their rows/columns.
Thank you and I'll post any code that is needed.

**Edit : I'm posting all I have:**

```
$keyword = str_replace(' ','', $_POST['keyword']);
$plaintext = str_replace(' ','', $_POST['plaintext']);

$key = str_split($keyword); //string to array
$plain = str_split($plaintext); //string to array

$alphabet = array(
                0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd', 4 => 'e', 5 => 'f',
                6 => 'g', 7=> 'h', 8 => 'i', 9 => 'j', 10 => 'k', 11 => 'l',
                12 => 'm', 13 => 'n', 14 => 'o', 15 => 'p', 16 => 'q', 17 => 'r',
                18 => 's', 19 => 't', 20 => 'u', 21 => 'v', 22 => 'w', 23 => 'x',
                24 => 'y');
for ($i=0; $i < count($key); $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j < count($alphabet) ; $j++) { 
            if ($keyword[$i] == $alphabet[$j]) {
                unset($alphabet[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    $keywordFilpped = array_flip($key);
    $alphabetFlipped = array_flip($alphabet);

    $mergedFlipped = $keywordFilpped + $alphabetFlipped;

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($mergedFlipped as $key => $value) {
        $mergedFlipped[$key] = $i;
        $i++;
    }

    $merged = array_flip($mergedFlipped);
$index = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j < 5; $j++) { 
            $matrix[$i][$j] = $merged[$index];
            $index++;
        }
    }
    echo "PLAYFAIR MATRIX:<br>";
    for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j < 5; $j++) { 
            echo $matrix[$i][$j];
        }
            echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: your code have single dimensional array, `echo array_search ('p', $alphabet)` .. this should work

Comment: Yes, it should work if I wanted to search from $alphabet, but I want to search $matrix. Therefore I should get two keys($i, $j for example).

Comment: also you don't need to specify numeric indexes, php will automatically do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a matrix should check with 2 for like following code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++)
{
     for($j = 1; $j <= 11; $j++)
     {
         if($array[$i][$j] == 'p') echo "row=$i and col = $j";
     }
}
```

in the above example i check all rows and rows cols

use from this function

```
function array_search2($needle, $haystack){
     $i = 0;
     foreach($haystack as $key => $value)
     {
         $j = 0;
         foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
         {
              if($value2 == $needle)
                   return array($i, $j);

               $j++;
         }
         $i++;
     }
     return false;
}
```

this function will return an array contain row and col of found status or false;

i tested with following data:

```
$array = array( 0 => array(0 => 'a', 1=> 'b'), 1 => array(0 => 'c', 1=> 'd'));
print_r(array_search2('d', $array));
// out put Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 )
```

Comment: The thing is that I won't be searching hard-core for one letter. That's the problem which bothers me.

Comment: i provided new function for you

Comment: Thank you!! It'works. Now I have to figure out how to do the rest! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I've improved your function, which will return keys if match found, irrespective of depth, See example below:

```
function getArrayKeys($needle, $haystack, $depth = 0) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {  
        if(is_array($value)){
            $result = getArrayKeys($needle, $value, $depth + 1);
            if(!empty($result) || $result === 0) {
                if (is_array($result)) {
                    $keys = array_merge($keys, $result);
                } else {
                    $keys[] = $result;
                }
                $keys[] = $key;
            }

            if(!empty($keys) && $depth > 0)
                return $keys;
        } elseif($value == $needle) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return !empty($keys) ? array_reverse($keys) : false;
}

$arr = array(
    array('A', 'B', 'C'),
    array('D', 'F', 'E'),
    array('Z', 'Y', 'X'),
    array('f' => '44', 'g' => array('99'))
);
$keys = getArrayKeys('99', $arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => g
    [2] => 0
)
```

See it running: https://eval.in/571698